# How to read XML file from web using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

When I connect to my HP ILO using the URL, http://ilo-ip/xmldata?item=All  it is returning a XML file in below format.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <RIMP>
- <HSI>
  <SPN>ProLiant DL385 G1</SPN> 
  <SBSN>ABCDEFG</SBSN> 
  <UUID>123456789</UUID> 
  </HSI>
- <MP>
  <ST>1</ST> 
  <PN>Integrated Lights-Out (iLO)</PN> 
  <FWRI>1.82</FWRI> 
  <HWRI>ASIC: 2</HWRI> 
  <SN>ILOABCDEFG</SN> 
  <UUID>ILO1234545</UUID> 
  </MP>
  </RIMP>
```

Is there any powershell command/script to read XML data from web URL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PowerShell uses the .Net framework XmlDocument so you could call the load method to load the xml into an XmlDocument object like this:

```
#Option 1    
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load("http://ilo-ip/xmldata?item=All")

#Option 2
[xml]$doc = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://ilo-ip/xmldata?item=All")


# Your XML will then be in the $doc and the names of the XML nodes can be used as
# properties to access the values they hold. This short example shows how you would
# access the value held in the SPN nodes from your sample XML 
Write-Host $doc.RIMP.HSI.SPN
```

If your looking for more information on working with the XML once it has been loaded check out [Dr. Tobias Weltner's eBook](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/) at PowerShell.com, [chapter 14](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/30/chapter-14-xml.aspx) covers XML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I read the code that is loaded? I couldn't find much help in internet.

Comment: the XML will be held in the $doc object so you can access it via property notation. For example 

Write-Host $doc.RIMP.HSI.SPN

This will write "ProLiant DL385 G1" to the console. What you can do is pipe $doc to Get-Member to get a list of properties e.g.

$doc | Get-Member

Comment: Hi Alan, I got an Exception When loaded the xml in both ways as you described. Exception is `"The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine"`

Comment: Hi ѕтƒ, are you able to access this xml file without using powershell? e.g. can you open it from your web browser

Answer (score 7):

Sure.  You can use the .NET WebClient object to download XML from the web and then use the [xml] type to interpret a string as XML like so:

```
$url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/rss.xml"
[xml]$xml = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
$xml.rss.channel | Foreach {$_.item} |
    Where {[DateTime]$_.pubDate -gt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)} |
    Format-Table Title
```