# Download XML File with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

when i attempt to download a xml file, i get not the xml content but den html code of the site.

```
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile("https://jira.issueviews:issue-xml/HELP-1141/HELP-1141.xml","C:\test.xml")

Select-Xml -Path ".\test.xml" -XPath '/channel/title' | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.name }
```

What is wrong ?

lg Joachim

Comment: Does this help? [How to read XML file from web using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819341/how-to-read-xml-file-from-web-using-powershell) Note that I simply Googled your question title. Have you read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ?

Comment: Sorry no this helps not. When i call the xml in the Browser the content is correct but when i download it, i get the html and javascript code.

Comment: If you want to use PowerShell to parse Jira, you might want to look at the REST API.  It's not XML but JSON is much more friendly:  https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/

Comment: okay thanks i hope this is the right direction i test it later.

Comment: fwiw - the browser also get's the html and javascript code but it knows what to show and what not. If you open developer tools (F12) on that page, you should see the same as what is in the downloaded xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @thepip3r that was the soultion for my cause.

```
Get-JiraIssue HELP-863 -Fields custom_123 | fl custom_123
$selection = $issueAll | Out-String
```

and next step i split the string to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

What's about using `Invoke-RestMethod`?

```
$Uri = "https://myurltothexml.com/foobar.xml"
(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri).OuterXml
```

Comment: I test it. Thanks.

Comment: Then please vote.